# Why does my website shows a Horizontal Scroll

Tags: wordpress

My website [byteindia](http://www.byteindia.com) is built on Thesis Theme and Wordpress and shows a horizontal scroll bar. I am not able to figure out why. Can anyone help me point out the problem?

Comment: I was able to reproduce it on Firefox/Chrome/Safari on Windows and Mac. Provided your screen resolution is set to 1280 or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the twitter widget, one of the divs in the iframe is rendering 300px wide.

Comment: Thanks it worked . data-width parameter to twitter follow button solved the issue.